# Adding ApproxMVBB into Android Studio

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, cmake

I'm trying to find the minimum volume bounding box given a set of point clouds in Android. This repo seem to contain the solution: https://github.com/gabyx/ApproxMVBB
But I'm having trouble installing it into my Android Project.
I've tried:

- using Cmake to build eigen (not approxMVBB yet) -> it fail at build time.
- using top level Cmake to build both eigen and approxMVBB in Android -> cant seem to find Eigen3Config.cmake
- built both of these two libs on my computer (Windows 10) using minGW64 -> created a dll and a dll.a file -> which seem to be incompatible with Android.
- copy {eigen_dir}/Eigen directly into scr/main/cpp, then hardcoded ApproxMVBB CMakeList with "include_directories(Eigen)" -> android build seem to have issue with Ninja.

I'm currently thinking that ApproxMVBB is simply incompatible with Android devices, but I'm not so sure. Any help or confirmation would be highly appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvm, I got frustrated so I wrote a MVBB for Java.
The code is here: https://github.com/ginofft/ARCoreDemo/blob/master/MVBB_Java/src/main/java/scr/MVBB.java

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).